# Javascript function does not call on firefox for android

Tags: javascript, android, function, firefox, call

In my html page, after loading the page, i dynamically add a piece of code containing this anchor

```
<a id="btnCall" class="btn_call_infobox" href="javascript:booking.userCall(189, '42.87930679999999', '10.964063200000055', this.id);">Call</a>
```

whenever i click this anchor in firefox on my desktop, `booking.userCall` is called correctly, but clicking the same link on firefox on my android (`fennec`), this function is NOT called.

Is there some difference between these two firefox versions that can explain my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about how much difference in browser version, but you should try below code

```
<a id="btnCall" class="btn_call_infobox" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:booking.userCall(189, '42.87930679999999', '10.964063200000055', this.id);">Call</a>
```